# Error parsing file: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup

Tags: salesforcedx, fields, knowledge, pipelines

Error when deploying knowledge fields via sfdx. I am getting following error :

[image]

Does anyone encounter this in the past ?

I have checked and current deploying user have the knowledge user checkbox checked on the org.
It is giving error on the object while I am NOT deploying the object file but only fields

Answer (score 1):

After struggle got it to work. The fact that I was using git to move file to and from   branches, I got a merge conflict on the file but ignore it, so There was this line added to the xml :

```
    <<<<<<<></<<<<<<>
       conflict here
    </<<<<<<>
```

Which was breaking my xml